# Dynamically adjust the height of ListView in qml

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I am using qml to write a interface for Wifi connection. There are a list of Wifi names on the interface, which I use ListView to implement. When we click a Wifi name, a virtual keyboard will pop up and allow us to input the Wifi password. I hope I could shorten the height of wifi list during inputing, so that there are no overlaps between wifi list and virtual keyboard. Otherwise when we input the password for the last few entries in the wifi list, the virtual keyboard will hide the wifi name and input field. How could I achieve this?

Here is the code for the ListView:

```
ListView {
            id: wifiList
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height - connectedWifi.y - connectedWifi.height
            visible: !wifiScanning.busy
            clip: true
            model: wifiModel
            currentIndex: -1
            onCountChanged: currentIndex=-1
            delegate: WifiItemDelegate {
                visible: connectedWifi.wifiName != ssid
                height: connectedWifi.wifiName != ssid ? columnHeight:0
                wifiErrorMessage: wifiErrorNotice
                enterPasswordHint: wifiRoot.enterPasswordHint
            }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use a conditional expression, like this: `height: keyboardIsVisible ? <short height> : <taller height>`

Answer (score 0):

I was using this in TableView. For ListView you can try;

```
        rowDelegate: Rectangle {
        color: styleData.selected ? 'skyblue' : (styleData.alternate 'whitesmoke' : 'white');
        height:50
        width: parent.width
        }
```